# the piece of code will not executed in async wait

Tags: node.js

the piace of code with if condition will not executed and the parent function will be executed after promise, but I dont understand why

```
let sql = `SELECT *
               FROM ${table}
               WHERE trader = '${trader}'
                 AND pair = '${data.symbol}'`;

    console.log(sql)

    let resp = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db.all(sql, function (err, rows) {

            console.log("err2")
            console.log(err)
            console.log("rows2")
            console.log(rows)
            return resolve(rows)
        })
    })
    if (resp[0]) { // <------- this will be executed after
        if (data.amount > resp[0].amount) {
            console.log('amount cambiato, comprato')
            // BUY Position
            await updatePosition(data, trader, 'buy');
        }

        if (data.amount < resp[0].amount) {
            console.log('amount cambiato, sellato')
            // BUY Position
            await updatePosition(data, trader, 'sell');
        }
        if (data.amount == resp[0].amount) {
            // BUY Position
            console.log('amount IDENTICO');
            await setCheckedTraderCoin(trader, data.symbol)
        }
    }
```

why this?

Comment: You forgot to add the code that call this function. Specifically, do you await this function in parent function?

Comment: FYI, you have NO error handling at all on your wrapped `db.all()` function.  In other words, you are silently ignoring errors and should be rejecting the promise upon error.

Answer (score 0):

This has to be in an `async` function since you're using `await`.  Thus, it returns a promise.

So, the caller must use `await` or `.then()` on that returned promise so it will also wait for the work to be done here.

ALL `async` functions return their promise upon the first `await` in the function.  That's why the caller has to also wait for that promise to resolve - otherwise it runs off and executes before any of the asynchronous work in this function is complete (as you've observed).

So, the solution to your caller running before the asynchronous work in this function has completed is for the caller to wait (using either `.then()` or `await`) for the returned promise to resolve before it does anything further.

---

Also, you need error handling on the promise that wraps `db.all()` so you reject that promise if there's an error:

```
let resp = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db.all(sql, function (err, rows) {
        if (err) {
            reject(err);
        } else {
            resolve(rows)
        }
    });
});
```

FYI, it would be preferable to use a driver for your database that directly supports promises so you don't have to manually wrap each call in a promise yourself.  Most database interfaces support promises by now.  Sometimes, you need a different version of the driver  - sometimes it's already available in the one you're using.  It depends upon which database/driver you are currently using.

Comment: which one "a drive for you database!?

Comment: @RogerAI - Which NPM module are you using for your database?

Comment: im using sqlite3 for sqlite

Comment: I don't know sqlite much.  You will need to find a version that supports promises.  I have no idea why sql databases for nodejs seem to be the last ones to support promises when most other DBs all have promise support built-in for awhile.